# Numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros

Tags: php, datetime

Converting month `without leading zero` to `with leading zero` is giving wrong output.

```
foreach(range(1,12) as $iM){
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n', $iM);
   $m=intval($date->format('m'));
   echo "[$iM, $m]";
}
```

**Outout:**

```
[1, 1][2, 3][3, 3][4, 5][5, 5][6, 7][7, 7][8, 8][9, 10][10, 10][11, 12][12, 12]
```

Comment: Did you just post this question and answer, which you're going to accept, within *one second* of each other?

Comment: @Ben Anyone having better solution than my one will be accepted instead of my own solution

Comment: I think you're missing the point of this site... It's for people with issues they can't solve to find helpful solutions. You've just put a problem, to which you already know the answer, for what purpose?

Comment: @Ben It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: It is, but then you risk people being pissed off they wasted their time to "help". It's meant that if you honestly solve you own problem, you can - but this smells more like trying to rep-farm.

Comment: Seriously, it's just fine to do it. You even have a GUI that allows to post both simultaneously. SO is meant to help as many people as possible, not just the individual how makes the original question.

Comment: @Ben I think if it would not be good to answer one's own question then SO would not allow people to answer their own question.

Comment: @patricksweeney You can see that I have accepted other solution than my one and that was the point of posting my own question and solution together. And those who have posted their solutions instead of unnecessarily downvoting my question or answer is being rewarded and will be rewarded by other users. So helpers will never be pissed off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you add a simple `var_dump($date);` statement inside your loop so you see what's going on.

You cannot have incomplete dates so the details that aren't provided are taken from current day. So when you say "February" PHP understands "31st February 2016" because today's 31st May 2016. Since that's an invalid date, PHP counts the appropriate days into next month and you get "2nd March 2016".

Despite what the number mean, you can just do this:

```
// Add leading zero
$m = sprintf('%02d', $iM);

// Remove leading zero
$iM = (int)$m;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(range(1,12) as $iM){
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('n', $iM);
   $m=sprintf('%02d', intval($date->format('m'));
   echo "[$iM, $m]";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am going with this solution where I am formatting the month as a date with common year and day, and variable month

**CODE:**

`foreach(range(1,12) as $iM){
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-d-n', "2016-01-".$iM);
   $m=intval($date->format('m'));
   echo "[$iM, $m]";
}`

**Outout:**

`[1, 1][2, 2][3, 3][4, 4][5, 5][6, 6][7, 7][8, 8][9, 9][10, 10][11, 11][12, 12]`